# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'size'

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, pytorch-dataloader

I'm trying to prepare some audio data for a Dataloader but I'm struggling with a few points. At the moment my data is organised into two lists `inputs` and `target`, which are both length `32`, but have different dimensions for their elements; `inputs[0].shape = (8, 3690288)` (8 mono audio tracks) and `target[0].shape = (2, 3690288)` (a single stereo mix).

I've converted each array to a tensor by:

```
tensor_inputs = torch.Tensor(inputs)
tensor_target = torch.Tensor(target)
```

which seems to work: `tensor_inputs.shape = torch.Size([32, 8, 3690288])`. I've then tried to convert each of these to a melspectrogram:

```
melspectrogram = torchaudio.transforms.melspectrogram(
        sr=44100,
        n_fft=1024,
        hop_length=512,
        n_mels=64)

tensor_input_specs = []

for i in range(len(tensor_inputs)):
    spec = mel_spectrogram(tensor_inputs[i])
    tensor_input_specs.append(spec)
    
tensor_target_specs = []

for i in range(len(tensor_target)):
    spec = mel_spectrogram(tensor_target[i])
    tensor_target_specs.append(spec)
```

and then move these into a Dataloader by doing:

```
dataset = TensorDataset(tensor_input_specs,tensor_target_specs)
iter = DataLoader(dataset)
```

However I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'size'`, which I imagine is due to the fact that I'm appending the spectrograms to a list, but I'm not sure how else to achieve this.

EDIT:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\BRUDAL~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_24968/2240294361.py in <module>
     14     tensor_target_specs.append(spec)
     15 
---> 16 dataset = TensorDataset(tensor_input_specs,tensor_target_specs)
     17 iter = DataLoader(dataset) # create your dataloader

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataset.py in __init__(self, *tensors)
    165 
    166     def __init__(self, *tensors: Tensor) -> None:
--> 167         assert all(tensors[0].size(0) == tensor.size(0) for tensor in tensors), "Size mismatch between tensors"
    168         self.tensors = tensors
    169 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataset.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    165 
    166     def __init__(self, *tensors: Tensor) -> None:
--> 167         assert all(tensors[0].size(0) == tensor.size(0) for tensor in tensors), "Size mismatch between tensors"
    168         self.tensors = tensors
    169 

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'size'
```

Comment: please paste the full error. I can't see where you used the `size` attribute.

Comment: @PrakharSharma I've just pasted the full error in an edit to the question.

Comment: here you go. In the error see line 167 with a `-->`. `assert all(tensors[0].size(0) == tensor.size(0)`. You need to pass tensors not a list. Obviously list does not have `size` attribute, it uses `len`. I would suggest you to print the`type` of `tensor_input_specs` and `tensor_target_specs` to make sure they are tensor.

Comment: Ok I got it. This is a list `tensor_target_specs = []`. Use [`torch.empty`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.empty.html) and then append using `torch.cat`.

Comment: @PrakharSharma Thank you for the pointers, they led me to finding what seems like the easiest way, through using `torch.stack(tensor_target_specs)`. I'll update with an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward method I've found is by stacking the list after the for loops, by using `torch.stack`:

```
tensor_input_specs = []

for i in range(len(tensor_inputs)):
    spec = mel_spectrogram(tensor_inputs[i])
    tensor_input_specs.append(spec)
    
tensor_input_specs = torch.stack(train_tensor_input_specs)

tensor_input_specs.shape

>>> torch.size([32, 8, 64, 7208])
```